# ScannerKit API - Apple Mach-O Linker Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, api

I am trying to add the ScannerKit API to my application i have added in the files need.
Added in the frame works but when i build and go i get over 50 errors.

All Apple Mach-O Linker Errors

Here are some:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__ZNSs6assignEPKcm", referenced from:
      __ZN8meatloaf10boundariesC2ESt6vectorINS_8scanlineESaIS2_EE in libScannerKit.a(boundaries.o)
      __ZN8meatloaf10boundaries15find_boundariesEv in libScannerKit.a(boundaries.o)
  "__Znwm", referenced from:
      -[SKLocalCodeRecognizer attemptRecognitionUsingFrame:] in libScannerKit.a(SKLocalCodeRecognizer.o)
      -[SKCodeIntegrityManager boundaryExistsInFrame:] in libScannerKit.a(SKCodeIntegrityManager.o)
      __ZNSt12_Vector_baseIiSaIiEE11_M_allocateEm in libScannerKit.a(SKCodeIntegrityManager.o)
      __ZNSt12_Vector_baseIN8meatloaf8scanlineESaIS1_EE11_M_allocateEm in libScannerKit.a(SKCodeIntegrityManager.o)
      __ZN5zxing28FastGreyscaleLuminanceSource22rotateCounterClockwiseEv in libScannerKit.a(FastGreyscaleLuminanceSource.o)
      __ZN5zxing24GlobalHistogramBinarizer11getBlackRowEiNS_3RefINS_8BitArrayEEE in libScannerKit.a(GlobalHistogramBinarizer.o)
      __ZN5zxing24GlobalHistogramBinarizer14getBlackMatrixEv in libScannerKit.a(GlobalHistogramBinarizer.o)
```

** **UPDATE** **

I have no longer got 50+ errors i fixed this buy changing "Other linker Flags" in build settings.

But i am still getting 3 errors!

If anyone could give me any idea as to what could be causing them:

```
Ld /Users/elistone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSSTestApp-ffjjgtzfgquuazdwtfemwyzzjmfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RSSTestApp.app/RSSTestApp normal armv7
    cd "/Users/elistone/Desktop/RSS Test App"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/elistone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSSTestApp-ffjjgtzfgquuazdwtfemwyzzjmfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/elistone/Desktop/RSS Test App/ScannerKit-4.2.2" -F/Users/elistone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSSTestApp-ffjjgtzfgquuazdwtfemwyzzjmfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-F/Users/elistone/Desktop/RSS Test App" -filelist /Users/elistone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSSTestApp-ffjjgtzfgquuazdwtfemwyzzjmfo/Build/Intermediates/RSSTestApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/RSSTestApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RSSTestApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -lstdc++ -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -lxml2 -lScannerKit -o /Users/elistone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSSTestApp-ffjjgtzfgquuazdwtfemwyzzjmfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RSSTestApp.app/RSSTestApp

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      __ZN5zxing6qrcode22DecodedBitStreamParser6appendERSsPKhmPKc in libScannerKit.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-B6EF2F7091225D41.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      __ZN5zxing6qrcode22DecodedBitStreamParser6appendERSsPKhmPKc in libScannerKit.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-B6EF2F7091225D41.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      __ZN5zxing6qrcode22DecodedBitStreamParser6appendERSsPKhmPKc in libScannerKit.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-B6EF2F7091225D41.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't linking to the proper frameworks under 'build settings.'

Comment: @CodaFi i looked it up and i don't have anything under "framework search paths" tried adding a link to the folder with everything inside and still no change 50+ errors.

Comment: You changed "Other linker Flags" to what? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

I added the framework libiconv.dylib.

Answer (score 1):

Antonio:

For me adding libstdc++.dylib to Link binary with Libraries list solved all my 8 problems

Comment: Who's Antonio? Do you mean António who commented to the question? Which 8 problems?

Comment: I reflected to Antonio in comments, he still had the problems, maybe it was similar to mine. At least worths a try.